# No data is save into my database with a form

Tags: laravel

I have a form where I put 3 information in it and a button submit. I complete the form and when I click on add, it redirect me into the main page, even if I return a `view` different from the one where it redirect me.

Here is my form :

```
    <form class="mt-3" method="POST" id="formCreation" action="{{ route('admin.liste.recette.ajouter.recette') }}">
@csrf
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titre" name="titreRecette" value="" required>

   <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="typeRecette" >
        <option selected></option>
        @foreach ($type_recettes as $type_recette)                  
            <option value="{{ $type_recette->id_type_recette }}">{{ $type_recette->libelle }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="saisonRecette" >
        <option selected></option>
        @foreach ($saisons as $saison)  
            <option value="{{ $saison->id_saison }}">{{ $saison->libelle }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <button type="submit" form="formCreation" class="btn my-4" style="color:white; background-color: #369d4a;">Add</button>

    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
       <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
</form>
```

My controller fuction to add an element :

```
    public function creer_recette(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([ // $data = $this->validate($request
        'titreRecette' => 'bail|required|between:5,40',
        'typeRecette' => 'bail|required',
        'saisonRecette' => 'bail|required'
    ]);
    $recette = new Recette();
    $recette->titre = $data['titreRecette'];
    $saison_recette = Saison::findOrFail($data['saisonRecette']);
    $type_recette = Type_recette::findOrFail($data['typeRecette']);
    $recette->saison()->associate($saison_recette);
    $recette->type_recette()->associate($type_recette);
    $recette->save();

    return view('admin/recette/admin_validation_ajout_recette');
 }
```

And my web.php :

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'liste-recette'], function(){
    Route::post('creation_recette', [RecetteController::class, 'creer_recette'])->name('admin.liste.recette.ajouter.recette');
});
```

No error displaying, just a redirection to the main page (I've gota function + a route for it)

Cordially

EDIT : The error came from some comments I add to my validate tab, Laravel didn't take it as comments and I don't know why...

Comment: Add 2 `dd()` function. One before validation: `dd($request)` and one after saving and before returning view: `dd($recette)`. First check if first one shows request object and then check if reaches the end and shows created object.

Comment: I have `Illuminate\Http\Request {#43 ▼` and alot of information below it. I guess its the `dd($request)`. If I remove `dd($recette)` it goes to the welcome page.

Comment: don't remove dd($recette). just remove dd($request) and check if you see result of dd($recette) that you put after calling save(). I wanna check if something is happening while saving or after that.

Comment: Its not working, no result. It goes straight to homepage.

Comment: If you remove the validate function, do you see the view?
Or if you delete everything exept "return view...", do you see the view? If so, place every line back one by one and see which one causes the problem. If I guess it's the validation that returns an error which you're not displaying.

Comment: When I remove everything, there is the view. Now, when I only let the `validate`, it does not show the view. That means the error come from the validation as you said. But why ?

Comment: I removed everything, did by hand add everything and its working now. I think its because I did add some comments and I don't know why, Laravel wasn't take it as comments...

Answer (score 0):

I assume your resource view file directory is `admin/recette/admin_validation_ajout_recette`

try changing the return view to

```
return view('admin.recette.admin_validation_ajout_recette');
```

Comment: I removed everything, did by hand add everything and its working now. I think its because I did add some comments and I don't know why, Laravel wasn't take it as comments...